# Setting currentTime on HTML5 video tag on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, html, video

I'm writing a jQuery plugin for the video tag on the ipad.  One of the things my plugin does is resumes playing a movie where you last quit watching it.  I'm having issues setting current time.  I've found I can only set it after the "`stalled`" event has fired.  The stalled seems to fire on an ipad after a movie starts playing (this is an HTTP live stream video).  I don't see this event in other environments i.e. google chrome on a PC.  So this code works but I feel uncomfortable using the `stalled` event.  I've tried `canplaythrough`, `playing` and others and in those cases my update to `currentTime` is ignored. Does anyone else have experience with this?

```
var theClass = this;
$(this.videoElement).bind("pause play stalled error abort progress waiting playing webkitfullscreenchange canplaythrough", null, function (e) {
    ///<summary>bind to the various events we are interested in during playback.  event state changes will be saved to
    ///local storage.  If we detect the media has finished playing we will exit fullscreen and trigger our mediaDone event</summary>
    if (e.type == "stalled" && theClass.resumeTriggered) {
        theClass.resumeTriggered = false;
        theClass.resumeTime = theClass.resumeTime + 0.1;

        $("#smpPlayerDebug").append("<p> seeking to time " + theClass.resumeTime + "</p>");
        e.srcElement.currentTime = theClass.resumeTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It just plain doesn't work. The iPad's support for controlling video play is weak, probably in Apple's attempt to create a standard experience (not allowing too much variation).

Comment: ..or Apple doesn't care about standards :)